# How do I disable paredit-ret in sly-mrepl*?

Tags: paredit, sly

I am trying to migrate from slime to sly. But I want to use `paredit` in `sly-mrepl`. Naive enabling of `paredit` in `sly-mrepl` leads to a problem where pressing `RET` in repl calls `paredit-ret`. But I want to call `sly-mrepl-return`.

How do I disable `paredit-ret` in `sly-mrepl`, call `sly-mrepl-return` and still use `paredit` goodness?

Comment: What is the "usual key rebinding"?

Comment: Good question! I meant something like: (add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook (lambda () (swap-paredit)))

Comment: I can't find the definition of `swap-paredit` - is that your own function? If so, can you edit your question and add this information (plus the info from the previous comment)? Questions should, to the extent possible, be complete in themselves, not depending on comments to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Following the suggestions from NickD I have rewritten my emacs config file to include the following advice:

```
;;; globally in every buffer and mode check if paredit-RET was called in
;;; the repl buffer and call sly-mrepl-return
(advice-add 'paredit-RET
            :after
            (lambda ()
              (when (string-prefix-p "*sly-mrepl for"
                                     (buffer-name (current-buffer)))
                (sly-mrepl-return))))
```

That ensures calling sly-mrepl-return after emacs calls paredit-RET when I am in a repl buffer and solves the problem described in my question. Perhaps the question should have been entitled: how do I call sly-mrepl-return after calling paredit-RET when I am in a sly-mrepl buffer?

Comment: If you modified the `paredit.el` file, there is no need to do that (and it's probably best if you don't): you can define your own modified function and make sure that it overrides the built-in function when loading  (probably through a hook, but I haven't checked what is available). Or you can [advise](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html/elisp.html#Advising-Functions) the original `paredit-RET` appropriately. Or you can try changing the keybinding of whatever keymap `sly-mrepl` uses only and leaving other keymaps alone. These are what I would consider before changing paredit itself.

Comment: Good idea, but it would be better if you provided working links to your suggestions. The advise link gives 404 error. I tried to change the keymapping in the sly mrepl only and I could not find a way to do it that would work.

Comment: Eh, sorry I screwed up: that advice link should be https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html

Comment: Dealing with the keymap properly involves understanding the priority of the various keymaps, so that you might change the appropriate one (something that I have not done and that I was too glib about in my original comment). You will need to do some investigation to do it properly. In the meantime, my first suggestion is probably the easiest to implement (but also probably the worst of the three).

Comment: Assuming that your current answer works to your satisfaction, I like it too :-) The only suggestion is to not spam the messages buffer with all those messages - it's okay for debugging, but after that it will be just noise.

Comment: You should realize however that the advised function is operative globally in every buffer and every mode, so you don't need to do it in the hook: the effect is the same.